# What is the best way to store city, state and country on MySQL?

Tags: data-structures, database-design, architecture, structure

When I have to store informations about city, state and country of users in a table, which one below is the best way?

1. Have 'state', 'city' and 'country' fields in the users table
2. Have 'id_city' in the users table and:

   - a table 'cities' with 'id', 'name' and 'id_state'
   - a table 'states' with 'id', 'name' and 'id_country'
   - a table 'countries' with 'id' and 'name'

The second one will avoid to have a wrong city in a wrong state and in a wrong country, as:

'Munique', 'NY' - 'Brazil'.

But when I need to select the country of an user I'll need 3 JOINS!

So, what's the best way to do it?

Comment: I would go with option 2. You want to to maintain referential integrity with the data.

Comment: Option 2. Saves disc space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick to option 2.

Actually, based on the use case and your application user amount. This would not be a issue. If it was, cache would help (These data is kind of static data. It is unusual for them to change).